# Change Button's Color in Another Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms named Form1 and Form2.

Each forms there are 3 buttons with the same name: Button1, Button2, and Button3.

What I want is when each color of Buttons in Form1 are changed, and then each color of Buttons in Form 2 are also changed. For example, Button 1 in Form 1 is green, so Button 1 in Form 1 is also green.

How can I do this ? These are what I have done and it doesn't work

Form1

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();    

private void Klik_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      counter++;
      if(counter==1)
      {
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Red;
        form2.Button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        form2.Button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        form2.Button3.BackColor = Color.Red;
      }
      if (counter > 1)
      {
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
        form2.Button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        form2.Button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
        form2.Button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
        counter = 0;
      }
    }

private void StripMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Show();
    }
```

Comment: what *exactly* doesn't work?

Comment: @ASh - my Buttons' color in Form2 didn't change. Can you help me to solve this ?

Comment: How do you create all forms?

Comment: Is this all the code?  I don't see anything that causes form2 to be shown.  I just want to be sure that wasn't implicit.

Comment: @Hambone - Yes that is all the code. I am confused what I must do in Form2 so that all Buttons in Form2 can change their colors like in Form1

Comment: @CharlesMay -  Oh I am sorry I forget to include that

Comment: have you debugged and seen if it is even going through?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? By default, the buttons added to form2 would have an access modifier of private.

Comment: @CharlesMay -  no errors but my buttons in form2 didn't change their colors. So here when color of buttons in Form1 are changed, automatically color of buttons in form2 changes same like buttons in form1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

In form2 create a Property called ButtonColor
`public Color ButtonColor = new Color();`

in the form2_paint method add the following

```
Button1.BackColor = ButtonColor;
Button2.BackColor = ButtonColor;
Button3.BackColor = ButtonColor;
```

Change form1 to

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();    

private void Klik_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      counter++;
      if(counter==1)
      {
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Red;
        form2.ButtonColor = Color.Red;
      }
      if (counter > 1)
      {
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
        form2.ButtonColor = Color.Green;
        counter = 0;
      }
        form2.Show();
        form2.Refresh();
    }
```