# How to change the color of buttons in form from another form using button?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have form named *frmMain* which has two buttons *btn1* and *btn2. Another form named *frmColor* has buttons named *btnRed* and *btnBlue*.

What I want to do is if I click *btn1* or *btn2*, it should go to the *frmColor*. In this form, clicking *btnRed* and *btnBlue* should change the color of *frmMain* to red and blue respectively.

Comment: Sorry I dont have a code to show because idk how to start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Button's Color in Another Form C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930476/change-buttons-color-in-another-form-c-sharp)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, we are not a code writing service. You should make use of the search functionality of the website, as this question has likely been asked before.

Comment: Add some tags. C# doesn't have buttons. Visual Studio?

Comment: somehow It helps me but all the buttons is changing color and what i want is just 1button

Comment: yeah nicomp visual studio sorry..^^..

Comment: yeah nicomp visual studio sorry..^^..

Comment: add some code and describe which technology you use

Comment: Again, add tags!

Comment: sorry DCON, i tried searching something like this but all i found is changing color of form not btn and rsha4u's answer

Answer (score 0):

on frmMain, you can have btn1 link to the click event of the btnRED on frmColor.

```
frmColor.btnRed.performclick()
```

then on the frmColor btnRed Click event, have it change the color of the frm

```
me.backcolor = color.red
```

another way is to bypass the click event on the frmColor button altogether, and just have the buttons on frmMain change the color of frmColor

frmMain buttons click event:

```
frmColor.backcolor = color.red
```